# Why isn't the hover effect working in my CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, mousehover

The `:hover` effect isn't working, and I'm not sure why.

I'm fairly new to CSS, and as I was experimenting with some exercises on my own, I came across an issue. When I hover over the `#hey` element, its color is supposed to change, but it's not working. I'm wondering what might be causing this problem and how I can resolve it. To help you understand better, I've also included a video demonstration and the code I've written.

[Here is a GIF link for you to see it better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITeIG.gif)

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 3000px;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  background-color: #003049;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid #003049;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
}

.header div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.header div:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.header div:nth-of-type(2):hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.header div:nth-of-type(3):hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.header div:nth-of-type(4):hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.header div:nth-of-type(5):hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

#hey {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#hey:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Trying something page</h1>

<section id="container">
  <div id="hey">HEY</div>
  <div class="header">
    <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have an element sitting on top of your "Hey". Even though your third rectangle has a transparent background, it's still there in the eyes of the browser. This means that when it looks to you like you're hovering over "Hey," you're actually hovering over your transparent background and the browser isn't getting the signal that "Hey" is being hovered on.

Depending on what your ultimate goal is, one solution is to move they "Hey" to the third rectangle.

HTML that replaces your third `div`.

```
<div style="background-color: #48bfe3" class="hey">
    <span class="text">Hey</span>
</div>
```

CSS that replaces all your styles for `#hey`.

```
.hey {
  /* styling the text */
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* aligning the text */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hey:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.hey .text {
  display: none;
}
.hey:hover .text {
  display: inline;
}
.hey .text:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

You can see the whole thing together in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/shainanigans/pen/Jjmxrvp).

Answer (score 0):

The hover function for the `#hey` element isn't working because there's already an active hover on the surrounding `div`.

Put another way, there's no access to the `#hey` element until you hover over the surrounding `div`. At that point, you're trying to trigger an additional hover, which the browser just ignores.

If you remove the `div` hover, you'll see the `#hey` hover works.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  height: 3000px;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#container {
  background-color: #003049;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid #003049;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
}

.header div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#hey {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#hey:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Trying something page</h1>

<section id="container">
  <div id="hey">HEY</div>
  <div class="header">
    <div style="background-color: #80ffdb"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #64dfdf"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #48bfe3"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #5390d9"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #6930c3"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you have the option, restructure the HTML. Try nesting the `#hey` element inside the `div`.